# What is HTTPPARSER (Node / Parser) in v8 memory heap for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, v8, heap-memory

In my memory heap snapshot, I have the following being shown as the biggest object as per retained size in WebStorm. What does this mean? I try to look at retainers but it basically just shows me a nested HTTPPARSER object.

What are these, and why are they being retained?

[image: Heap Snapshot]

Comment: did you figure out what HTTPPARSER object is?